# Changing the toolbar item placement on iPad

Tags: ios, swiftui, toolbar

Let's take the Shortcuts app for example.

On the iOS App:
[image: Shortcuts on iOS]

On the iPadOS App:
[image: Shortcuts on iPadOS]

As you can see, the toolbar items were on `.navigationBarTrailing` on iPhone, but it moved to `.navigationBarLeading` on iPad.

My code looks like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("This is a test app.")
                .navigationTitle("All Shortcuts")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Select") {
                            // Do something...
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            // Do something else...
                        }) {
                            Label("Some Other Action", systemImage: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected on iPhone, but on iPad the toolbar items appear at the trailing end of the toolbar. I want the toolbar items to be on the trailing end for iPhones and on the leading end for iPads, just like the Shortcuts app. How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check for the used device type:

```
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ?
                           .navigationBarLeading : .navigationBarTrailing) {
```

Comment: I think the original question was that the OP wanted it to be `. navigationBarTrailing`, but it switched to leading. That being said, I think you have the start of the fix in this answer.

Comment: For anyone who’s going to use this: Keep in mind that with iPhone Pro Max models on landscape mode, this won’t work. The toolbar items will be on the “iphone” side.